List authors with corresponding institutions
I am trying to compile an article using R Markdown. I am struggling to have the authors one after the other or as a list with their corresponding institutions (repeated). I have tried many ways but am not getting what I expect when knitting.
I have tried the following options in the YAML section:
First option:
author:
  - A¹²
  - B¹²³
  - C⁴

affiliations:
  - "¹ W"
  - "² X"
  - "³ Y"
  - "⁴ Z"

output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    rticles::springer_article: default
    df_print: paged
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    latex_engine: pdflatex
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    rticles::springer_article: default
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
  bookdown::word_document2:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true

compact-title: false
bibliography: references.bib
link-citations: true
csl: "ecology-and-society.csl"

Second option:
author:
- name: "A"
  affiliation: 
  - "W"
  - "X"
- name: "B"
  affiliation: 
  - "W"
  - "X"
  - "Y"
- name: "C"
  affiliation: 
  - "Z"

date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"

output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    rticles::springer_article: default
    df_print: paged
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    latex_engine: pdflatex
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    rticles::springer_article: default
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
  bookdown::word_document2:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true

compact-title: false
bibliography: references.bib
link-citations: true
csl: "ecology-and-society.csl"
---


If I try this, the solution works, but affiliations are placed after the abstract.
